# Android: Getting location with mobile internet(NETWORK_PROVIDER)

Tags: android, locationlistener

I'm developing an application with the first activity checking for network and Gps, and if at least network is present, it tries to get current location(no special accuracy needed).
In WIFI mode, everything works perfect. In GPS mode(if available) everything perfect too.
The problem is with the mobile internet(no WIFI/GPS). In this mode, the onLocationChanged method, gives me some coordinates just after the location requests start. The accuracy is very bad for sure. The thing is I can't find the difference between WIFI and MOBILE internet.

..the code

```
private void startLocationListeners(){
    try
    {
        if (isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            if (isGPSEnabled)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, locationListener);
                Log.d("TAG", "GPS");
                }

            else{
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, locationListener);
                Log.d("TAG", "Network"); 
                }
            }
        }

    catch (Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("Error TAG : LocationManager", "problem", e);
        }
}
```

..and here the onLocationchanged

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            stopLocationListeners();
            coordinates=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            Toast.makeText(context, coordinates, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startCamera();
            }
    };
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually turning off wifi to do your test?  If so, this is exactly the expected behaviour.

Network location finding works by sending a request to the internet saying "I can see the following wifi networks and cell towers, can you tell me where I am?"  When wifi is on you have lots of networks, and since wifi is a short range signal, you can get a pretty good idea of the location.  If you turn wifi off, then all you have is the location of cell towers, and those are much further apart, so the accuracy plummets.

Comment: I have already checked it. The same issue. Is it possible the bad mobile internet reception to be the problem? Also, I've noticed in logcat, that when I get location, sometimes the onLocationChanged() is triggered more than one time. I use the stopLocationListeners() method to prevent that and get a single location, but it doesn'seem to work.